# Sort list items from random child

Tags: javascript, html, list, sorting

**UPDATE:**
As many people refer that the question was not enough clear I'm going to try to explain it better ^_^ thanks for your help and patience!

I have a list of around 15 items (that will increase or decrease). Each item consist of a logo with the URL to their website. The items were manually alphabetically ordered.

```
  <ul class="myClass">
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company A" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo1.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company B" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo2.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company C" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo3.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL"  title="Company D" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo4.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company E" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo5.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

Everytime the page is load (also the first time) I would like to ramdonly chose one child and then display the list reordered starting from the selected child followed by the rest without losing the alphabetically order.

**For example,** if the ramdon selects the 3rd child of my list then it should display a list like this:

```
<ul class="myClass">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="URL" title="Company C" target="_blank">
        <span class="logo">
          <img src="images/logo3.jpg">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="URL" title="Company D" target="_blank">
        <span class="logo">
          <img src="images/logo4.jpg">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="URL" title="Company E" target="_blank">
        <span class="logo">
          <img src="images/logo5.jpg">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>

    ...

    <li class="item">
      <a href="URL"  title="Company A" target="_blank">
        <span class="logo">
          <img src="images/logo1.jpg">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="URL" title="Company B" target="_blank">
        <span class="logo">
          <img src="images/logo2.jpg">
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Hi! This is the code I'm trying to make it work but it does nothing :( The ramdom works, but how can I reorder the list items??

```
    function randomizeChild(){
      var listItems = [];

      $('ul.retailers li').each( function() {
          listItems.push(this);   
      });

      var randomChild = Math.floor(Math.random() * listItems.length);
      var newOrder = listItems.splice(listItems.indexOf(randomChild)).concat(listItems);

      console.log("Random Child --->" + randomChild);

  }

  randomizeChild();
```

I hope this time my question is clearer. Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: please add your js script so people can figure out where/what part is giving you false result

Comment: Hi @Carsten and @melvnberd! I'm sorry but I cannot place here the code... but just imagine that inside each '<li>' there are a few '<div>' with '<a>'. The request was first only random order (which I success) but now they (my customer) wants an "ordered random sort".... So my problem is that I don't know how to split the a list from any child and displayed following the order... don't know where to start :( Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

try giving your ul an id

```
<ul id='sorted_list'>
```

then in javascript you can do:

```
elementlist = ['A', 'B']
randomelement = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementlist.length)

list = document.getElementById('sorted_list')
listelement = document.createElement('LI')
listelement.textContent(elementlist[randomelement])
list.appentChild(listelement)
```

combine this with zvonas answer, and you should manage it.

Answer (score -2):

To help you to get started:

```
var elems = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
var selectedLetter = 'D';
var newOrder = elems.splice(elems.indexOf(selectedLetter)).concat(elems);
```

Comment: Thanks @zvona and @oliver! Is there any way to do it not using the content of the '<li>'? A, B, C, D.... is just for the example. Every list element is more complex (divs and links inside each one) to put them into an array... Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Good to hear this gets you started. I'm just surprised about the downvotes of this answer. And I don't understand what your content really is, could you update the question?

Comment: Hi @zvona I've updated the question. I hope you can help me with this.... Thanks!