# Split Array using IndexOf is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, split, indexof

this is a question link to another question I've already asked (see here: [Sort list items from random child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215725/sort-list-items-from-random-child/)).

The problem is that I have a list of items that I want to split from a random item. I'm trying with "IndexOf()" but it returns always -1. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="myClass">
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company A" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo1.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company B" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo2.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company C" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo3.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL"  title="Company D" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo4.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="URL" title="Company E" target="_blank">
            <span class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo5.jpg">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function randomizeChild(){
        var listItems = [];

        $('ul.myClass li').each( function() {
          listItems.push(this);   
        });

        var randomChild = Math.round(Math.random() * listItems.length);

        console.log("Random Child ---> " + randomChild);

        var indexToSplit = listItems.indexOf(randomChild);
        var first = listItems.slice(0, indexToSplit);
        var second = listItems.slice(indexToSplit + 1);

        console.log(indexToSplit); // it returns always -1 :(
        console.log(first, second);

       }
```

Comment: Your `randomChild` is already a random index, no need to pass it into `indexOf` as well... Right now, you are basically asking "give me the index of the index..."

Comment: I think `listItems` is a String array and `randomChild` holds an integer or double so `listItems.indexOf(randomChild)` would always return `-1`

Comment: Just use more jQuery, and it solves itself -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fdz52g2y/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you are getting the index which is an integer and checking the indexOf of the integer which doesn't exist in your array. You have an array of elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/h2a4L67k/

Try this:

```
function randomizeChild() {
    var listItems = [];

    $('ul.myClass li').each(function () {
        listItems.push(this);
    });

    var randomChild = Math.round(Math.random() * listItems.length);

    console.log("Random Child ---> " + randomChild);

    var randomChildObject = listItems[randomChild];
    var indexToSplit = listItems.indexOf(randomChildObject);
    var first = listItems.slice(0, indexToSplit);
    var second = listItems.slice(indexToSplit + 1);

    console.log(indexToSplit); // it returns always -1 :(
    console.log(first, second);

}
```

You don't even need to do what is above. You already have a random index so just use it right away:

```
function randomizeChild() {
    var listItems = [];

    $('ul.myClass li').each(function () {
        listItems.push(this);
    });

    var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * listItems.length);

    console.log("Random Child ---> " + randomIndex);

    var first = listItems.slice(0, randomIndex);
    var second = listItems.slice(randomIndex + 1);

    console.log(randomIndex); // it returns always -1 :(
    console.log(first, second);

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h2a4L67k/1/

Comment: when we already have `randomChild` then what is the point of extracting the `listItems[randomChild]` and then finding `listItems.indexOf(randomChildObject)`? the value would not change!

Comment: Yes I was just showing in his current example what was wrong. I added a portion below explaining it was extra work but thanks for pointing it out! =]